# Using component without even declaring it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I am very new to Vue and I have read an article or two about it (probably vaguely).

Also, Since I have some understanding of react, I tend to assume certain things to work the same way (but probably they do not)

Anyway, I just started with Quasar and was going through the Quasar boilerplate code

In the myLayout.vue file, I see  being used inside my template

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="lHh Lpr lFf">
    <q-layout-header>
      <q-toolbar
        color="negative"
      >
        <q-btn
          flat
          dense
          round
          @click="leftDrawerOpen = !leftDrawerOpen"
          aria-label="Menu"
        >
          <q-icon name="menu" />
        </q-btn>
```

based on my vaguely understanding, I thought for every component we are using to whom we need to pass props we need to import it as well but unfortunately I can't see it in my import-script area

```
<script>
import { openURL } from 'quasar'

export default {
  name: 'MyLayout',
  data () {
    return {
      leftDrawerOpen: this.$q.platform.is.desktop
    }
  },
  methods: {
    openURL
  }
}
</script>
```

I would've thought the script to be something like

```
<script>
import { openURL } from 'quasar'
import {q-icon} from "quasar"
```

or at least something like that but here we only have

```
 import { openURL } from 'quasar'
```

Also, Even if we remove the above snippet, our boilerplate app looks to be working fine so here are my two questions

**Question 1:** What is the use of `import { openURL } from 'quasar'` (like what it does)

**Question 2:** How can template contain `<quasar-icon>` or `<quasar-whatever>` without even importing it in script tag?

Comment: You can globally import components in vue.  See [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration).  In the case of Quasar I believe they do that for you when you specify a component in the `quasar.conf.js` file.

Comment: One important thing that this has to be set earliest you can in the execution of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can template contain `<quasar-icon>` or `<quasar-whatever>` without even importing it in script tag?

There are two ways to import components. The first way (which I recommend, and being most similar to React) is to import the component and add it to the `components` option inside the component that you want to use it within.

**App.vue**

```vue
<div>
  <my-component/>
</div>
```

```es6
import MyComponent from 'my-component'

export default {
  components: {
    MyComponent
  }
}
```

The second way is to import it globally for use within any Vue component in your app. You need only do this once in the entry script of your app. This is what Quasar is doing.

**main.js**

```es6
import Vue from 'vue'
import MyComponent from 'my-component'

Vue.component('my-component', MyComponent)
```

> What is the use of `import { openURL } from 'quasar'` (like what it does)

I'm not familiar with Quasar, so I can't give you a specific answer here (I don't know what `openURL` does). You should check the Quasar docs.

`openURL` is being used as a method here. Perhaps it is being called from somewhere in the template (which you have excluded from the question).

Comment: libraries like vuetify are imported via a plugin with Vue.use(plugin). I guess it is the same with quasar.

Answer (score 0):

A1) Import statement is 1 way (es6) way to split your code into different files and then import functions/objects/vars from other files or npm modules see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

A2) Vue allows 2 mechanisms to register components. Global and local. Globally registered components does not have to be imported and registered in every component before use (in template or render fn). See URL from comment above https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Global-Registration